# How to display user values from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I created a form to collect user information and then saved it in localstorage.

To finish the programming I want to display this information in an HTML page. However, the way I did the information appears and disappears quickly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


   <form style="width:50%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 1.9%;">
      <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">

      <h2 style="font-size: 1.0rem;">Selecione a data</h2>

      <input id="datepicker" width="396" />

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="matriz" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
         <div class="input-group-append">
           <span class="input-group-text">Matriz</span>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group mb-3">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rep" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
         <div class="input-group-append">
           <span class="input-group-text">Rep</span>
         </div>
      </div>

   <p>Saved info is:</p>
   <p id="currentDate"></p>
   <p id="currentRep"></p>
   <p id="currentMatriz"></p>

<script>
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap5'
    });
</script>

<script>
   store();

   function store(){ 
   const inputDate = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
   const inputRep = document.getElementById('rep').value;
   const inputMatriz = document.getElementById('matriz').value;
      
   window.localStorage.setItem('Date', String(inputDate));
   window.localStorage.setItem("Rep", String(inputRep));
   window.localStorage.setItem("Matriz", String(inputMatriz));


   document.getElementById("currentDate").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem("Date");
   document.getElementById("currentRep").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Rep");
   document.getElementById("currentMatriz").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Matriz");
   }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to display the user values in html page from local storage?

Comment: Why are you reloading the page?

Comment: The `store()` function is never called, if it were called, then the values would not appear due to the `window.location.reload()` reloading the page and discarding your HTML changes.

Comment: I removed `window.location.reload()` and now the information submitted by the form does not appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the key "Rep" but then getting "Reprodutor". This might be the issue why you don't see the values appear on the page

Answer (score 0):

Your code does the following steps (in order):

1. Read value of DOM elements
2. Save that value to LocalStorage
3. Read value from LocalStorage and inject into DOM elements

Since the DOM elements are empty on page load, you'll push 'nothing' to the LocalStorage, read 'nothing' so there's nothing to show.

Consider the following example where we change the order if needed:

```js
store();

function store(){

    // Get elements
    const inputDate = document.getElementById('datepicker');
    const inputRep = document.getElementById('rep');
    const inputMatriz = document.getElementById('matriz');

    // IF there is NOTHING in LocalStorage
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('Date') === null) {

        // Set dumy value so we'll not push 'empty' things to LocalStorage
        inputDate.innerHTML = 'Dummy date';
        inputRep.innerHTML = 'Dummy rep';
        inputMatriz.innerHTML = 'Dummy Matriz';

        // Save to localStorage
        window.localStorage.setItem('Date', inputDate.innerHTML);
        window.localStorage.setItem("Rep", inputRep.innerHTML);
        window.localStorage.setItem("Matriz", inputMatriz.innerHTML);
    } else {

        // Set to DOM eleemnts
        inputDate.innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem("Date");
        inputRep.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Rep");
        inputMatriz.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("Matriz");
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Saved info is:</p>
<p id="currentDate"></p>
<p id="currentReprodutor"></p>
<p id="currentMatriz"></p>

<hr >

<div id='datepicker'></div>
<div id='rep'></div>
<div id='matriz'></div>
```

**Note**: This does not work in SO snippets, try it offline

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it still didn't work because the dumy values don't change when I send new information, also the values are not being displayed in the html page.

Comment: Oeps, there were some errors. I've fixed them. I've tested this offline and works, the props are saved in the localstorage and retreived on reload.

Comment: Hi @0stone0 Could you post the complete code? Because I tried again and I couldn't make it work, I keep having the same errors.

Comment: What errors? That is the complete code...

Comment: The submitted information is not shown in the HTML page. I edited the question, now I put my complete code.